# Django Rest Framework customizations

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

Currently this is what I have in `urls.py`:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
   url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
   url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

`views.py`:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class StoreList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

I want to make it so that when I do a POST command to the site, I can execute custom functions, so for example:

`POST http://example.com/users/1/add {'id': 'joe', 'name' = 'joe1'}`

or

`POST http://example.com/users/1/add?id=joe&name=joe1`

Will execute the `add` function, with the input `id` = `joe`. So inside the function I can do something like:

```
if id == 'john':
  return Response("NO")
else:
  return Response("Yes")
```

Then it would return a print out for example

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en-us
Content-Length: 123
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 11:11:11 GMT
Expires: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 11:22:11 GMT
Handler: product-detail
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 11:11:11 GMT

{
    "result": "Function success"
}
```

So that my other functions can use the dict that was returned.

Does anyone know how I can go with doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF has an inbuilt mechanism to help with this but on request method support is GET. Here's the reference from the documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter

The work around could be to override the `post` function in your view and take the argument `add` as input to it. For example,

> urls.py

```
url(r'users/(?P<id>[\d]+)/(?P<method>add)/$, UserListView.as_view)
```

> views.py

```
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
         method = kwargs.get('method')   # value should be "add"
         # check if the method exist in the view
         # if yes, call it
         method_obj = getattr(self, method)
         if method_obj:
                data = request.POST #{'id':'joe}
                id = data.get('id') 
                method_obj(id=id)
   def add(self, id):
         #do soemthing
```

> Update:

POST data i.e. `{"id":"joe"}` is available in the `request` and can be accessed via `request.POST`.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I get the inputs for the function add? For mine the input should be `{'id': 'joe'}`, but it can be something like `id joe` is fine. So ie: `POST http://example.com/users/1/add?id=joe&name=joe1`

Comment: I am assuming the input is part of POST request payload, I have updated the answer. Please take a look

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear. What I meant by that is that the POST will take in those values as inputs, and the function `add` will use it. So inside `add` if I reference to `id`, it should have the value `joe`

Comment: What you said was still achievable just needed some more code. I have updated the answer further

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However when I try to print out the values of data, I'm getting nothing :\ Seems like it's not reading the input correctly. How would you do it if something like `POST http://example.com/users/1/add?id=joe&name=joe1` is wanted? I think it'd be easier

Comment: Its generally not appropriate to submit POST data as query string. It should be sent as part of request body. Which is why you don't see any data when you print it

Comment: Yea, so I tried to make the `add` function just print out the id, but it printed out nothing. That's why I tried to print out `data`, but it showed nothing, so `id` becomes nothing too

Comment: The reason you don't see anything is because you not submitting the payload as part of `request body` but as `query string`. Can you also add your test code.